# How to lock on Solaris 10?

Tags: command-line, solaris, lock

On Linux I use `flock lock command` to execute a command with an exclusive lock.

What is the standard operating system command of Solaris 10 to do the same in a shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a small [Usenet discussion](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.unix.solaris/browse_frm/thread/dd2213fd89266561/35757ccc590a85ab) I use the following as a workaround for `flock -n lockfile -c command`:

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ $# != 4 -o "$1" = '-h' ] ; then
   echo "Usage: flock -n lockfile -c command" >&2
   exit 1
fi

lockfile=$2
command=$4

set -o noclobber
if 2>/dev/null : > "$lockfile" ; then
   trap 'rm -f "$lockfile"' EXIT
   $BASH -c "$command"
else
   exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no `flock` or similar command for Solaris. If I want to do simple locking I use `mkdir` as it's a atomic operation and avoids potential race conditions with the usual check file exists/touch combination.

```
if ! mkdir /tmp/lockdir >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo >&2 "Lock exists exiting"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Is `mkdir` always atomic? I seem to recall buggy NFS implementations where it isn't, but then Solaris NFS is less buggy than most.

Comment: @Gilles: I don't know - I always create lock files in /tmp.

Comment: @Gilles, `mkdir` is meant to be atomic over NFS and is actually why it's recommended over a open/creat with O_EXCL. Now it is very well possible that there exist buggy implementations. Having said that, of all places, /tmp is the least likely to be over NFS

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Buggy NFS implementations aren't that rare: http://www.mail-archive.com/freebsd-hackers@freebsd.org/msg20456.html http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=983724 http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1037310 …

Answer (score 0):

I'd combine the two ideas:

```
getLock() {
    PROG=$( basename $0 )
    SHAREDLOCK="/tmp/lockdir-$PROG"

    if mkdir "$SHAREDLOCK" >/dev/null 2>&1
    then
            trap 'rmdir "$SHAREDLOCK"' EXIT
            chmod 0 "$SHAREDLOCK" # discourage anyone from messing with it else the rmdir might fail
    else
            echo >&2 "Lock ($SHAREDLOCK) exists. exiting"
            exit 1
    fi
```

}